# rails javascript in text_field_tag

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, security, jquery-select2, textfield

I'm kind of new to javascript/jQuery and rails at the moment and was using a text_field_tag with select2-rails in order to create a tagging with autocomplete etc.

It's working pretty great now but just out of curiosity I placed

< script >alert("hello");< /script >

(without the spaces) in the textbox and the alert popped up. Isn't that pretty unsafe? Is there anything that I should be adding to stop the javascript from being executed in that text_field?

Edit::
This is my javascript on that page to apply to my text_field_tag:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#filter-in-postkey-select2").select2( {  
        width                   : "450px",   
        placeholder             : "No postkeys. Add some here now!",  
        minimumInputLength      : 1,  
        maximumSelectionSize    : 5,  
        tags                    : ["red", "brown", "green"],  
        tokenSeparators         : [",", " "]  
    });  
});
```

and my text field is simply:

```
<%= text_field_tag "filter-in-postkey-select2" %>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You are submitting a form and after a new page load this alert box is displaying? Or is the alert box being displayed without a form post?

Comment: @Ash I don't think a post is being carried out because I haven't submitted the data inside the text field yet. The < script > alert pops up as soon as I have completed closing the < /script > tag.

Comment: Actually one of the links provided by another SO member here kindly shows an example where you can try inserting some javascript to see what I mean :) http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/6XvqX/41/

Comment: I see what you mean now. I'd file an issue with that project (Select2 is it?) and then not worry too much about it. You should be validating all values server side before sending the data to other clients.

Answer (score 1):

you can escape the user's input with a plugin such as [XSS_terminate](https://github.com/look/xss_terminate)

then it's as simple as doing this in your model:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  xss_terminate :except => [ :your_input_field_to_be_exempt ]
end
```

Comment: thanks for the plugin :) but please correct my if I am wrong - if the javascript is being executed before it is being submitted does this sanitisation come later? Is the purpose of this plugin to prevent foreign code from being saved into the DB?